# Trouble debugging maxmatch algorithm in python

Tags: debugging

I have been working on a maxmatch algorithm to tokenize hashtags, comparing to word list in nltk but I have trouble with debugging.

The gist of algorithm is as the following:

```
function MAXMATCH (sentence, dictionary D) returns word sequence W
  if sentence is empty
    return empty list
  for i ← length(sentence) downto 1
    firstword = first i chars of sentence
    remainder = rest of sentence
    if InDictionary(firstword, D)
      return list(firstword, MaxMatch(remainder,dictionary) )
# no word was found, so make a one-character word
  firstword = first char of sentence
  remainder = rest of sentence
  return list(firstword, MaxMatch(remainder,dictionary) )
```

The following is my python implementation of it.
I inserted a number of `print` trying to debug here and there.

```
from nltk.corpus import words # words is a Python list
wordlist = set(words.words())

lst = []
def max_match(hashtag, wordlist):
    if not hashtag:
        return None
    for i in range(len(hashtag)-1, -1, -1):
        first_word = (hashtag[0:i+1])
        print "Firstword: " + first_word
        remainder = hashtag[i+1:len(hashtag)]
        print "Remainder: " + remainder
        if first_word in wordlist:
            print "Found: " + first_word
            lst.append(first_word)
            print lst
            max_match(remainder, wordlist)

# if no word is found, make one-character word
    first_word = hashtag[0]
    remainder = hashtag[1:len(hashtag)]
    lst.append(first_word)
    max_match(remainder, wordlist)
    return lst

print max_match('labourvictory', wordlist)
```

The last line, `print max_match('labourvictory', wordlist)` should return list ['labour', 'victory'] and I expected it to quit because of `if not hashtag return None` part and yet, for reason I don't understand it proceeds on and all hell breaks loose.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recursive functions, most common bug is not returning a value at correct point. I modified your code as per the given pseudocode gist. The problem in your code is that you are not returning any value when you have found a word in the dictionary.

```
def max_match(hashtag, wordlist):
    if not hashtag:
        return []
    for i in range(len(hashtag)-1, -1, -1):
        first_word = (hashtag[0:i+1])
        remainder = hashtag[i+1:len(hashtag)]
        if first_word in wordlist:
            return [first_word] + max_match(remainder, wordlist)

    # if no word is found, make one-character word
    first_word = hashtag[0]
    remainder = hashtag[1:len(hashtag)]

    return [first_word] + max_match(remainder, wordlist)
```